# Is there a function in R that return Package Depends, Imports and LinkingTo?

Tags: r, import, depends

In CRAN, each package has Package Depends, Imports and LinkingTo http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html. Is there a build-in function or a function from an R package that can return the same information? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something that queries CRAN to get this information, or something that gets the information about a currently-installed package?

Comment: Bioconductor's [pkgDepTools](http://bioconductor.org/packages/1.9/bioc/vignettes/pkgDepTools/inst/doc/pkgDepTools.pdf) might be of use.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Both `available.packages()` and `installed.packages()` have it:

```
R> AP <- available.packages()
R> dim(AP)
[1] 6793   17
R> AP[1:5, c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo")]                                                                                                                                                                                          
            Depends                                               Imports          LinkingTo                                                                                                                                              
A3          "R (>= 2.15.0), xtable, pbapply"                      NA               NA                                                                                                                                                     
abbyyR      "R (>= 3.2.0)"                                        "httr, XML"      NA                                                                                                                                                     
abc         "R (>= 2.10), abc.data, nnet, quantreg, MASS, locfit" NA               NA                                                                                                                                                     
ABCanalysis "R (>= 2.10)"                                         "Hmisc, plotrix" NA                                                                                                                                                     
abc.data    "R (>= 2.10)"                                         NA               NA                                                                                                                                                     
R>
```

Answer (score 1):

The package DESCRIPTION file has this info. The function in the `utils` package `packageDescription` will parse and read this. See [`?packageDescription`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/packageDescription.html)